# Return entire data set after .filter not just the filtered objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, filtering, javascript-objects

Lets say I'm doing a filter on:

```
documents = {
    "aggregations": null, 
    "results": [{"firstName": "Sid", "lastName": "Villain", "gender": "m"},{"firstName": "Dave", "lastName": "Jones", "gender": "m"},{"firstName": "Peggy", "lastName": "Sue", "gender": "f"}], 
    "summary": {"took": 1, "count": 230}
}
```

I will filter on the array of objects `results`. When the filter is done I am left with just the objects filtered out in the array e.g.

```
filteredDocuments = {"firstName": "Sid", "lastName": "Villain", "gender": "m"},{"firstName": "Dave", "lastName": "Jones", "gender": "m"}
```

I don't want to lose `"aggregations": null` and `"summary": {"took": 1, "count": 230}`, so how can I get a similar data set back minus any thing that wasn't in the filter?

I've done a [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-local-array-of-objects-4be6kb?file=src/app/app.component.ts) with a filter in operation, however any type of filter similar to this does the same thing.

```
this.filteredDocuments = this.documents.results.filter((person) => person.gender === "m")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to return a copy of the object and at the same time overwrite (or merge in other circumstances) the `results` property.

```js
const documents = {
  "aggregations": null,
  "results": [{ "firstName": "Sid", "lastName": "Villain", "gender": "m" }, { "firstName": "Dave", "lastName": "Jones", "gender": "m" }, { "firstName": "Peggy", "lastName": "Sue", "gender": "f" }],
  "summary": { "took": 1, "count": 230 }
}

const filteredDocuments = {
  ...documents,
  results: documents.results.filter((person) => person.gender === "m")
};

console.log(filteredDocuments);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the object with [`Object#assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and assign the filter result to the `results` property of that object:

```js
const documents = {
    "aggregations": null, 
    "results": [{"firstName": "Sid", "lastName": "Villain", "gender": "m"},{"firstName": "Dave", "lastName": "Jones", "gender": "m"},{"firstName": "Peggy", "lastName": "Sue", "gender": "f"}], 
    "summary": {"took": 1, "count": 230}
}
const onlyM = Object.assign({}, documents);
onlyM.results = documents.results.filter((person) => person.gender === "m")
console.log(onlyM);
```